# SQL Server Stored Procedure WHERE Clause IF CASE No Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a stored procedure with default values, which I set to `NULL`. In the `WHERE` clause, for each value specified, rather than `NULL` or not given (where it would also be `NULL`), I would like the column to equal this value, otherwise, I would like to search without this column being in the `WHERE` clause. The basic structure looks something like this:

```
// Set up the stored procedure
USE Table;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchTable

    // Specify value(s)
    @Name varchar(50) = NULL

AS

    // Set up the query
    IF(@Name IS NOT NULL
        SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name=@Name;

    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Table

BEGIN
END
```

I have more than 1 parameter, and so, with this logic, I would need 2 `IF`'s for every parameter. As you can imagine, this gets boring, time-consuming, and error-prone fast.

I would like to move this logic into the query, preferably into the WHERE clause, but any way I have found will cause errors (besides exceptions, which would require just as many `IF`'s). SQL Server doesn't like `IF`'s in the `WHERE` clause as far as I know, and with CASE I would have to specify the column, which I do not want to do.

What should I do?

**Edit**:
I have SQL Server version 2012, so please concentrate on this or any recent versions in your answer.

Comment: Please just go and read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: The newer article there is related to SQL Server 2008. I understand there are many differences between this and SQL Server 2012, so will these differences impact whether or not this solution will work for me?

Comment: Also, even if you think the answer is obvious, please either put it as an answer or vote to close the question. It helps people in the future looking at this question.

Comment: I never put this as an answer because I'm just signposting you towards someone else's work. The 2008 answers should still be valid. If you believe that 2012/14 changes things, that might make a difference, but my general advice would be to follow Erland's advice and only post a question if it's not actually working for you.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Sorry, I didn't want to force you to make a question if you didn't want to. :) I will try that article and if it doesn't work I'll post another comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about performance, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE @Name is null or Name = @Name;
```

Often, having an `or` condition gets in the way of efficient use of indexes.  Perhaps this isn't a problem in your case, though.

Comment: Was in the middle of suggesting this same thing

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. The downside to this is that indexes may not be used properly and thus the performance may not be great.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (@Name Is Null Or Name = @Name)
      And (@Col2 Is Null Or Col2 = @Col2)
      And (@Col3 Is Null Or Col3 = @Col3)
```

Each column condition is "anded". Or is used to apply that column condition only if `@var` is not null. So for example, if this is called with just `@Name` populated, it is equivalent to `Where Name = @Name`. If both @`Name` and `@Col2` are populated, it is equivalent to `Where Name = @Name And Col2 = @Col2`.

Comment: @trysis, explanation added.

Comment: I know, I saw, thanks. Another question, why won't indices be used?

Comment: Generally with OR condition the SQL server can't decide which index to use properly. For example, if we had an index on Name, SQL server won't use Index Seek even if the @Name parameter is specified because the next ORed clause can produce more rows. It would most likely do Index Scan on it but that too might depend on what query was executed first few times (called parameter sniffing). In the end you will have to be more cautious about something like this and keep an eye in 'production'.

Comment: At the end of the day... you are trying to optimize the speed of the sql server execution plan. This trumps eliminating a few lines of code (and nullifying your indexes). Efficiency in code is great, as long as it doesn't slow down the actual site. If efficiency is not an issue... carry on.